# `userToken` must be provided while running on client-side please make sure to call client.setUser" in getstream io

Tags: flutter, dart, feed, getstream-io, dio

Im working on the getstream io feed api integration.But am getting this error
userToken` must be provided while running on client-side please make sure to call client.setUser"
when i call this method,
final userToken = await client.frontendToken(uId);

How can i fix this?
Please help..

[image]

Comment: The error message seems self-explanatory. Did you "call client.setUser"? What happened when you did?

Comment: for calling client.setUser we need to pass token ,so in the client.frontendToken method im generating token,so as to pass it to setUser

Comment: created the API for generating tokens..Thus it worked